# comparing two arrays and getting similarity java

Tags: java, arrays, compare

I have two arrays on my own custom objects. I need to find the amount of similarity to score it. The user will submit a recipe that they cooked and the program should score how accurate it was to the original recipe. Here is what I tried:

```
int increase = 100 / userRecipe.size();
for(int i = 0; i < userRecipe.size(); i++) {
    if(userRecipe.get(i).equals(bookRecipe.get(i))) {
         percent += increase;
    }
}
```

However the major flaw with this solution is that in theory, these two recipes below are scored 0% accuracy when it should be 75%.

```
Item[] userRecipe = {milk, sugar, eggs, flour};
Item[] bookRecipe = {sugar, eggs, flour};
```

However it doesn't work because the two lists are different lengths so it doesn't work. If anyone knows how I should approach this, I'd appreciate it. Here are the problems

- The userRecipe list may be larger or smaller than the bookRecipe
- The offset makes scoring inaccurate

I am a relative beginner to java, so if anyone wouldn't mind giving me a good solution, I'd appreciate it! Thank you.

Comment: For your example, if `userRecipe` had sugar at index 3 and flour at index 1, would the accuracy still be expected to be 75% or should it be 25% since they are out of order?

Comment: it would still be 75%. Assume that The lists have already been sorted, by the way.

Comment: How do you score someone who overspecifies the recipe.  Includes 5 items but only 2 match.   Or includes 6 items of which 4 match the recipe exactly.

Comment: You should lose percent for each mistake, and yes that is a mistake so -percent.

Comment: So for my question, it would be 40% (2 out of 5) and (66% 4 out of 6)?

Comment: What would the percentages be for two userRecipes of one ingredient each.  `[eggs]` for one and `[milk]` for the other.

Comment: 0% for [eggs] vs [milk]. Also yes for other q.

Comment: Just to be certain before you accept my answer, please check my percentages.

Comment: Yes, it produces the results I expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my take on this.

- use a set to hold the recipe ingredients.
- then simply stream each submission and get the count of correct ingredients.
- then compute the percentage based on the larger of the submitted ingredient count and the recipe count (to penalize for over specifying)

This works regardless of the order of the ingredients and works in linear time for each user due to the use of a set to hold the recipe.

```
Set<String> bookRecipe = Set.of("sugar", "eggs", "flour");
double ingredientCount = bookRecipe.size();

List<List<String>> entries = List.of(List.of("milk", "sugar"),
        List.of("milk", "sugar", "eggs", "flour"),
        List.of("milk", "sugar", "eggs", "flour", "beer"),
        List.of("milk", "sugar", "whiskey", "paint"),
        List.of("milk", "sugar", "eggs", "beer", "hay"),
        List.of("milk", "beer", "hay"),
        List.of("milk", "sugar", "eggs", "beer", "hay",
                "orange juice"));

System.out.println("Recipe: " + bookRecipe + "\n");
for (List<String> submission : entries) {
    long correct = submission.stream()
            .filter(ingredient -> bookRecipe.contains(ingredient))
            .count();
    
    double percentage = correct
            / Math.max(ingredientCount, submission.size());
    
    System.out.printf("%3d%% - %s%n",
            (int) (percentage * 100), submission);
}
```

prints

```
Recipe: [eggs, flour, sugar]

 33% - [milk, sugar]
 33% - [eggs]
  0% - [milk]
 75% - [milk, sugar, eggs, flour]
 60% - [milk, sugar, eggs, flour, beer]
 25% - [milk, sugar, whiskey, paint]
 40% - [milk, sugar, eggs, beer, hay]
  0% - [milk, beer, hay]
  0% - [beer, chips, salsa]
 33% - [milk, sugar, eggs, beer, hay, orange juice]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the lists are in sorted order, to solve this problem optimally (without running in O(n^2) time), this is a classic *manipulate two pointers* problem.

```java
int increase = 100 / userRecipe.size();
int userIndex = 0;
int bookIndex = 0;
while (bookIndex < boockRecipe.size() && userIndex < userRecipe.size()) {
    if (userRecipe.get(userIndex).equals(bookRecipe.get(bookIndex))) {
        percentage += increase;
        bookIndex++;
    }
    userIndex++;
}
```

This will only loop through each list *once*.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean Something like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {





    String[] s1 = {"A", "B", "D"};//userRecipe
    String[] s2 = {"A", "B", "C","D","E"};//bookRecipe

    int percent=0;

    int largerCount=s1.length>s2.length ? s1.length:s2.length;
    int smallerCount=s1.length<s2.length ? s1.length:s2.length;
    String[] largeArr =s1.length>s2.length ?s1:s2;
    String[] smallerArr =s1.length<s2.length ?s1:s2;

    for(String x:largeArr)
        for (String y:smallerArr) {
            if (x==y) percent++;
        }

    System.out.println((percent*100)/largerCount+"%");

}
```